# Lodge, Cheers,?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, word-sequence

Fill in the missing word:

> Lodge, Cheers, ??? - Realnet Longed Rabid.

The only hint you get is that

> a book is involved.

**d'alar'cop** and **Florian F** should be able to solve this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cryptic Answer :

> **ChaB**

---

Cryptic Explanation :

> Reference is **GEB**

---

Full Explanation :

> realnet is anagram for eternal
>  longed is anagram for golden
>  rabid is anagram for braid
>  **Godel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid, also known as GEB, is a 1979 book by Douglas Hofstadter**
>  lodge is anagram for Godel
>  cheers is anagram for Escher
>  so ChaB is anagram for Bach
>  Reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach

Comment: Well done! I thought this one would be easy.

Comment: I see your excitement, and I don't want to throw water on it.  Your answer needs some context though because I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Leppy is right, what are we talking about? All I see is a sequence of meaningless words (chab, geb, realnet). Can you explain please?

Comment: @leoll2 , some explanation is now included

Comment: Why ChaB and not chab?

Comment: I like the way you've split it up: one-word answer, one-word explanation, full  explanation. Maybe you could say unspoilertaggedly that this is what you're doing, so that people know which spoilers to look at?

Comment: @randal'thor , nice puzzle, after seeing "lodge" & "longed", I was checking what other similarities exist between the left side and the right side, but there were none. then I noticed that realnet was not a real word, so I went looking for anagrams, to get the solution. Regarding "unspoilertaggedly", yes that sounds good.

Comment: @LeppyR64 , anything should be fine, but that was my preference, to Capitalise as per name and also Capitalise as per question formatting.

Comment: Since "ChaB" isn't a word, wouldn't any of the other arrangements of the letters also be acceptable answers? What is it about ChaB that makes it uniquely the answer among these? Bahc, Bhac, Bhca, Bcah, Bcha, Abch, Abhc, Ahbc, Acbh, Achb, Ahcb, Habc, Hacb, Hbac, Hbca, Hcab, Hcba, Cabh, Cahb, Cbah, Cbha, Chab, Chba

Comment: @IanMacDonald , I think there is no single unique answer, only one single unique concept which can be represented by any one of the possibilities in your comment.